# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate won't update my database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

I am teaching myself NodeJS while working on an app. I use Mongoose and Axios.

On one section of the app I display the partners and when I click on update I get a form with the informations of the selected partner in order to update them.

The client-side sends in the infos to the server but the server won't  update the entries in the database. Here is my server side

```
app.post("/api/partner/update", (req, res) => {
const id = req.body.id;
const fullname = req.body.fullname;
const email = req.body.email;
const phones = req.body.phones;
const shops = req.body.shops;
const company = req.body.company;

console.log("The body is ",req.body) //It returns the correct data from the client's side submited data

Partner.findOneAndUpdate(id, mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false),
 {
    "fullname": fullname,
    "email": email,
    "phones": phones,
    "shops":shops,
    "company": company
  },
  (err, document) => {
    if (err) return err;
    //console.log(document);
    res.send({ document });  

  }
);});
```

Here is my model :

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const partnerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fullname: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: 1,
      required: true
    },
    phones: {
      type: Array
    },
    company: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50,
      required: true
    },
    shops: {
      type: Array,
      default: 0
    },
    is_valid: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    validated_by: {
      type: String
    },

    created_by: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    updated_by: {
      type: String
    },
    deleted_by: {
      type: String
    },
    deleted_at: {
      type: Date,
      default: null
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at"
    }
  }
);

const Partner = mongoose.model("Partner", partnerSchema)
module.exports ={Partner}
```

I don't understand why it is not updating the fields in the dataBase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax for findOneAndUpdate as per the docs:

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { name: 'jason bourne' }, options, callback)
```

Change db query to this:

```
let query = {_id: id };
let dataToUpdate= {
    "fullname": fullname,
    "email": email,
    "phones": phones,
    "shops":shops,
    "company": company
  }
let options = {useFindAndModify: false}  // useFindAndModify set to false at query level
// options = {useFindAndModify: false,new:true} if you want updated docs in return


 Partner.findOneAndUpdate(query,dataToUpdate,options,(err, document) => {
        if (err) return err;
        //console.log(document);
        res.send({ document });  

      }
    )
```

**To set Deprecation Warnings on or off at mongoose level use option**

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
```

**Read more here:**

[Deprecation Warnings](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html)

[findOneAndReplace](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

You can also use `findByIdAndUpdate` method:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options, callback)
```

You can enable promises to make code more readable and testable:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Answer (score 1):

Refering the doc, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html
first parameter of `findOneAndUpdate` should be a filter object, not the id directly.

So please try `Partner.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': id},....`